# Repeating arbitrary nested for loops

Tags: objective-c, arrays, for-loop

I've been trying for a few hours to work out an algorithm that can achieve the following conditions:

- Take an arbitrary number, n arrays (each populated with strings), where each array will be a figurative 'parent' to the subsequent array
- For each object (a string) in an array, combine that string with subsequent arrays' strings
- Add the combination to an (just one) array
- Repeat for **all** linear combinations of each object

I think this is best explained with an example:

e.g. For three arrays 
`NSArray *input = 
@[[@"cat",@"dog",@"mouse"],[@"apple",@"banana"],[@"green"]]`

produce an output that goes something like this:

`@[
@"catapplegreen",
@"catbananagreen",
@"dogapplegreen",
@"dogbananagreen",
@"mouseapplegreen",
@"mousebananagreen"
];`

I've tried nesting `for` loops but can't think of a way of allowing there to be an arbitrary amount of loops, as there needs to be one loop or 'level' per array in the input.

If anyone has any advice (even just pointers of what to look into to tackle this problem) I'd be most grateful.

Comment: So the problem is that the arrays can be nested more than 2 deep?

Comment: Does it then move onto the second array? Such as `applecatgreen`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, yeah there are an arbitrary number of nestings (realistically no more than 10)

Comment: @Evan It doesn't, no... Just moves from 0, through all combinations of 1, which also goes through all possible combinations of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically what I think you want to do it a Depth-First Traversal of your data.

Which you could do with a function such as

```
- (void)DepthFirstOnString:(NSString *)string children:(NSArray *)children {
    if (children.count < 1) {
        // You're finished
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
        return;
    } else {
        // Keep going
        NSArray *next = children[0];
        NSMutableArray *remaining = [children mutableCopy];
        [remaining removeObject:next];

        [next enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSMutableString *currentString = [string mutableCopy];
            [currentString appendString:obj];

            [self DepthFirstOnString:currentString children:remaining];
        }];
    }
}
```

being called by this code:

```
NSArray *input =  @[@[@"cat",@"dog",@"mouse"], @[@"apple",@"banana"], @[@"green"]];

NSArray *first = input[0];
NSMutableArray *remaining = [input mutableCopy];
[remaining removeObject:first];

[first enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [self DepthFirstOnString:obj children:remaining];
}];
```

Not the neatest code but hopefully gives you an idea of where to take it.

Comment: Recursion is a good solution when you have loop-type logic, but with a variable number of levels of nesting.

Comment: This works great... thank you so much! I'll have to look into DFS much more.